# R Snow show all created clusters

Tags: r, snow

I'm doing some stuff that uses `snow` clusters.  Currently the only way I know of to see how many active clusters there are is to open the task manager -> resource manager -> sort by name and look for `RScript` objects.  Is there a way to do this in R?

Also the reason I ask this is so I can delete the previously created clusters.  Sometimes I'll see `RScript` objects still around after running `stopCluster()` in R.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Note: So far all the clusters I've done are `localhost/SOCK` clusters to use 2nd core on my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a `cluster` object, frequently called `cl`, which you can inspect.

From the help page:

```
## Two workers run on the local machine as a SOCK cluster.
cl <- makeCluster(c("localhost","localhost"), type = "SOCK")
clusterApply(cl, 1:2, get("+"), 3)
stopCluster(cl)
```

That `cl` object will tell you about hosts.